# Lecture notes on Ergodic Theory.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory, online-resources, lecture-notes

I am looking for a good lecture notes on Ergodic Theory. It should be self sufficient and easy for someone who is taking the course for the first time and for self reading.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46889/reference-for-ergodic-theory?rq=1

Comment: at user8795: AFAICT you are creator of (lecture-notes) tag. For this reason, I wanted to mention that I made a post on meta discussing the tag: [What about (lecture-notes) tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26600)

Comment: I will just point out that a recent answer on meta (see the link above) suggests removing the tag (lecture-notes).

Answer (score 2):

C. E. Silva's *Invitation to Ergodic Theory* published by AMS.

Intended as an introduction to the subject for undergraduate level and develops the required measure theory within the text itself.

Answer (score 1):

Halmos , lectures on ergodic theory 1956 .

Charles Walkden , ergodic theory 2018 .